# Java: Access element of an arrayList which is a value in a TreeMap

Tags: java, data-structures, treemap

I have a TreeMap which maps a key to an ArrayList. I would like access each of the elements stored inside each ArrayList of the TreeMap.

Is there a method to do this?

The elements of the ArrayList are of type String.

Comment: You have a `Map` which maps a key to a `List` — you should ignore the fact that a TreeMap and an ArrayList were chosen as the implementation details, and program to the interfaces.  This doesn't change the question and shouldn't affect the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to loop over all the elements in your TreeMap lists. You can achieve this easily with Java 8 streams:

```
treeMap.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream).forEach(element -> doStuff(element));
```

For more information, please refer to:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html